# Proving an Isomorphism between $\mathbb{R} / (f) $ and $\mathbb{R} / (x^2) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

$f= x^2 + bx + c \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Given that the discriminant of $f$ is $0$ show the expression in the title holds. I have written $f$ as $$f = (x- \alpha)^2$$ where $\alpha$ is the repeated root of $f$. I am unsure of how to setup a homomorphism such that the kernel is $(f)$.

Comment: Send $p(x)+(f)\in\mathbb{R}[x]/(f)$ to $p(x+\alpha)+(x^2)\in\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: What would the homomorphism be between $R[x]$ and $R[x] / (x^2)$ that has $(f)$ as the kernel? Trying to utilise the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: From $\mathbb{R}[x]$ to $\mathbb{R}/(x^2)$ send $p(x)$ to $p(x+\alpha)+(x^2)$. Any polynomial of the form $f(x)g(x)$ will be send to $f(x+\alpha)g(x+\alpha)+(x^2)=x^2g(x+\alpha)+(x^2)=0+(x^2)$. Conversely, if $p(x)$ is send to $0+(x^2)$ that means that $p(x+\alpha)$ is a multiple of $x^2$. Therefore, $p(x)$ is a multiple of $(x-\alpha)^2=f(x)$.